# SpringBoot application with tomcat consumes more resource in Openshift

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, openshift

I'm deploying a spring boot web application in an Openshift environment. Since we're using web components like JSPs and CSSs in the same boot project we are deploying the application as a WAR file in the Openshift environment. And I have also added the tomcat-embed-jasper to resolve these web components and execute the WAR file.

But the problem is when I deploy it in the Openshift environment, the application consumes more than 1GB of the resource. Is there any way I could reduce the memory consumption by the application?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD
COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY src /build/src/

WORKDIR /build/
RUN mvn -DskipTests=true package

FROM tomcat:8.0.51-jre8-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

I tried changing to different tomcat images, but when I deploy, only the tomcat starts and my application isn't getting deployed inside tomcat. I'm looking for suggestions for this as well. Below are logged when I use a different tomcat image.

**image : tomcat:10.0.0-jdk8-adoptopenjdk-openj9**

```
15-Sep-2020 07:03:31.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war]
15-Sep-2020 07:03:38.884 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-Sep-2020 07:03:39.048 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war] has finished in [7,563] ms
15-Sep-2020 07:03:39.054 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
15-Sep-2020 07:03:39.067 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [7671] milliseconds
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with consuming more memory? Do you have requests/limits set in your container?

Comment: The application's memory consumption sometimes rises to 2Gb. And we have several other applications running as well. So we feel if theapplication consumes less it'd be better. Right now I set 2GB as limit.

Answer (score 0):

As shown here

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD
COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY src /build/src/
```

You are coping the complete src folder.
I think this will be taking lot of memory.

I would suggest to exclude the mvn packge from the DockerFile, run mvn packge separately and use only the following part independently:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.51-jre8-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

Comment: Thanks KayV. So you want me to build the war locally and copy it to Openshift environment, Am I correct?

Comment: I tried this option. But it doesn't make any difference. It still consumes the same amount.